# Is it possible to chain together input bindings in a function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to chain together input bindings?

I have a use case where the function would:

- be triggered by a HttpTrigger
- use a value from the trigger to get some data from a storage table by partition key and row key
- then use a value from the retrieved table data to get even more data from a different table storage
- ... and for good measure, use an output binding to write to a Cosmos db

I can see how to add multiple input bindings, but I can't see how I can chain the sequence together.

Comment: have a look at a sample in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#sample-read-multiple-table-entities-in-c

Comment: I've been using the sample, but still can't see any way to chain the values of one input to a second input?

Comment: AzureFunctions supports only one trigger in the Fan-in pattern. Basically there are two options for this solution such as built-in the body of the function (like it is done in the sample) or process decomposition into the small functions and using some integration technique (storage queue, etc.) for message pipeline (state). Other technique is to use a lease blob for distributed state or Durable Functions https://buildazure.com/2017/08/15/scaling-azure-functions-with-durable-functions/